# Azure WebJobs Size Limit

Tags: azure, azure-webjobs

What are the possible options to overcome the size limit problem of webjob in Azure. During uploading the webjob(.zip file) the size is limited to 100 MB now. And my zipped file accounts to 105 MB. So i'm not able to upload my webjob into the site.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general I would recommend deploying your WebJobs as part of your Website, just put each WebJob under `wwwroot\App_Data\jobs\{triggered/continuous}\{jobname}`.

That way you don't have a manual step for deploying a WebJob and they can be deployed in any Azure Websites supported deployment option (FTP, WebDeploy, git, dropbox, [DebugConsole](http://azure.microsoft.com/blog/2014/03/04/windows-azure-websites-online-tools-you-should-know-about/), mercurial, VS Team Services, ...).

> Note: One exception is deploying a scheduled WebJob, currently you can't deploy a schedule in this way.

Answer (score 1):

You can FTP into the website and upload the files that way